# SQL: create counter for duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I would like to create an integer counter for duplicate entries on an intermediate table in an import step. Let's say I have a table called `FinalTable`, which looks like this:

`FinalTable`

```
ID       Date          SameDateCounter
1003     2012/01/01    NULL
1004     2012/02/01    NULL
1005     2012/03/01    1
1006     2012/03/01    2
1007     2012/03/01    3
1008     2012/04/01    1
1009     2012/04/01    2
```

And has a unique constraint on `(Date, SameDateCounter)`. In the intermediate step the data is in `IntermediateTable`, which looks exactly like `FinalTable` except that it doesn't have any constraints. So the starting point for this problem is here:.

`IntermediateTable`:

```
ID       Date          SameDateCounter
1003     2012/01/01    NULL
1004     2012/02/01    NULL
1005     2012/03/01    NULL
1006     2012/03/01    NULL
1007     2012/03/01    NULL
1008     2012/04/01    NULL
1009     2012/04/01    NULL
```

And I need to generate the values for SameDateCounter, starting at one, where the date appears more than once.

Comment: You could try with rank and partition by as described in this [article ](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx)

Comment: expected result = as shown in FinalTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function combined with a `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
;WITH Data AS
(  
   SELECT
       ID, Date,
       SameDateCounter = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY ID DESC)
   FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
)
SELECT *
FROM Data
```

The `PARTITION BY Date` clause groups every separate value of `Date` into its own "partition", and `ROW_NUMBER()` hands out numbers starting at 1, for each partition.

So your `SameDayCounter` will start at 1 for each new day and will show the rows for that particular day.

Comment: yea that was my thought but had not time to write it:)